# PHP OOP Class query

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli

Good evening, I'm new to OOP and I'm trying to get some results with MYSQLI fetch assoc but I have an issue: only one result is returned in an infinite loop. Please see the code below and let me know what the issue can be:

```
class Database{
    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $db;
    private $mysqli;


    function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$data) {
        $this->host     = $host;
        $this->user     = $user;
        $this->pass     = $pass;
        $this->data     = $data;
        $this->mysqli   = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->data);
    }

    public function GetNewsArticles(){
        $querystr="SELECT newsarticle.Id, newsarticle.Title from newsarticle GROUP BY newsarticle.Id ORDER BY newsarticle.id DESC";
        return $this->mysqli->query($querystr);
    }

}

$db= new Database("localhost","root","","news");
$db->GetNewsArticles();

while($row = $db->GetNewsArticles()->fetch_assoc()){ 
    echo $row["Id"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = $db->GetNewsArticles()->fetch_assoc())
```

This line causes your function to be executed and to return fresh results over and over. Thus you end up in an infinite loop, always fetching the first result.

The fix:

```
$result = $db->GetNewsArticles();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
    echo $row["Id"];
}
```

Comment: @coder_1432 You're welcome. Be sure to upvote the good answers and to select one of them. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the mysqli_result object in a variable that you return from `GetNewsArticles()` and call `fetch_assoc()` on *that*:

```
$db= new Database("localhost","root","","news");
$results = $db->GetNewsArticles();

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){ 
    echo $row["Id"];
}
```